# ActiveMQ - Limiting number of pending messages in queue without affecting the producer

Tags: activemq-classic

ActiveMQ 5.15.4

Context: the producer I'm working with publishes to many different queues.

Things I've tried:

1.

```
<policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="10 mb">
</policyEntry>
```

This correctly limits the queue size, but it throttles the producer, as described [here](http://activemq.apache.org/per-destination-policies.html). This leads to other, non-problematic queues being af

2.

```
<policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="false" memoryLimit="10 mb">
</policyEntry>
```

Doesn't seem to do limit queue size.

3.

I've tried to use **messageEvictionStrategy** and **pendingMessageLimitStrategy** but they don't seem to work for queues, only topics.

Am I missing some other possible strategy?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Time To Live value on the messages to control how long they stay in the Queue, otherwise the broker will either block the producer using flow control or page the messages to disk if you disable it.  Queues are not generally meant for fixed size messaging as the assumption on the Queue is that the contents are important and should not be discarded unless the sender allows for it via a TTL.